# R - Extract substring

Tags: r

I have a column with list of names which includes their Title.

Example:

```
Ryerson, Master. John Borie
Corey, Mrs. Percy C (Mary Phyllis Elizabeth Miller)
```

I would like to extract their Titles from their names i.e., Mr, Mrs, Master etc

Function:

```
In[79]:
mystring="Wilkes, Master. James (Ellen Needs)"
In[80]:
substr(sub(".*,", "", mystring),2,which(strsplit(sub(".*,", "", mystring),"")[[1]]==".")-1)
Out[80]:
[1] "Master"
```

When I test the above function on one name, it works fine. But, when I apply the same function to the column with list of names, it is extracting only two characters.

Example: Ryerson, Master. John Borie

I would like to see 'Master' extracted from this name whereas I see 'Ma'.

```
[436] "Mi" "Mi" "Mr" "Mr" "Mr" "Mr" "Mr" "Mr" "Ms" "Mr" "Ma" "Mi" "Mr" "Mi" "Ma"
```

I don't know what's wrong with the function. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you show all the patterns?

Comment: Is it always the second word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example showed, we can match one or more characters that are not a `,` (`[^,]+`) followed by `,` and one or more space (`\\s+`) from the beginning (`^`) of the string or `|` a `dot` (`\\.`) followed by any character till the end of the string (`.*`) and replace it with `''`.

```
gsub("^[^,]+,\\s+|\\..*$", "", str1)
#[1] "Master" "Mrs"
```

If it is the second 'word', then `word` can be used

```
library(stringr)
word(str1, 2)
#[1] "Master." "Mrs."
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("Ryerson, Master. John Borie", 
       "Corey, Mrs. Percy C (Mary Phyllis Elizabeth Miller)")
```

Comment: haha, was just about to post the `word` part (hence my question in comments) :)

Comment: @Sotos I saw your comment and got the hint.. :-)

Comment: helpful little function. Just found out about it yesterday.

Comment: @akrun - Could you please explain gsub() solution?

Comment: @ksp Updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any spaces in the vector containing names eg:Mr. Mahesh, you can try this code

```
my <- c("MR. Arun", "Master. mahesh")
y <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(my," "))
z <- y[,1]
print(z)
[1] "MR."     "Master."
```

Comment: can i know the issue

Comment: The issue is that you have `.` at the end where as in the expected output it is not there.  Second, you are making some assumptions which the OP didn't specify

Comment: thanks akrun, we can use gsub for . and my assumptions was not as exact as OP specified